# Unable to implement CryptoJS in Typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript

I have developed an application by using typescript plugin.

**Note: No angular only typescript and jquery**

In my application i want to use CryptoJS but not succeed.

The problem is that CryptoJS is not included in the build file. I am using rollupJs

```
npm run build
```

Is there any settings in rollupJs so that CryptoJS can be included in the bundle?

Please find the sample code what i have used

I have tried in two different ways

1st way

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
console.log(CryptoJS.HmacSHA1("Message", "Key"));
```

It throws an error Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

2nd way

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
console.log(CryptoJS.HmacSHA1("Message", "Key"));
```

It throws an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'HmacSHA1' of null

Thanks,

Sanjib

Comment: your true problem is not CryptoJS but "require is not defined": https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=require+is+not+defined  (more than 67k questions -  I guess you might find a solution)

Comment: @jps I have tried both ways, It might be by using require or by using import. When build CryptoJS is not included in build file

Comment: This probably has something to do with how CommonJS vs. ES6 modules work. You seem to be working in an ES6 environment (`import`/`export`) where `require` doesn't exist, but trying to use a CommonJS module which includes most everything on NPM. What `import X from 'Y'` actually does in ES6 is import the *default* export from the module as X; but CJS modules don't have default exports - CJS modules only export one value. The compatibility shim the TS compiler and Webpack use is that they treat that one value as the "default" export, but it seems Rollup doesn't do this by default.

Comment: My guess is you should be using something like https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs to handle compatibililty if you're making an app with NPM dependencies in the general case. (It will probably be the case for a very long time that you won't be able to rely on all your dependencies to support ES6 modules.)

Comment: Alternately check if you have `esModuleInterop` enabled in the `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json`, the TS compiler *should* be able to handle this for you. That said, when working with a bundler, I prefer TS to do a "clean" transpile and let the bunder do the work of correctly loading modules, since that's kind of its job.